# What is the meaning of ダッサ？

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, slang

I don't understand the meaning of ダッサ in the following sentence:

> なんだこいつらダッサ面白れえ！

The context is a fight between two enemy factions. I think it is a contraction of ダサい "uncool" but I don't understand its meaning when used before an adjective, as in the sentence above.

Comment: Reminds me of 「キモかわいい」... The answer here might be of some help... -> http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26019/a-different-way-to-join-i-adjectives/26021#26021

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ダッサ is from ダサい. Joining two arbitrary adjectives like this is nonstandard, but native speakers occasionally do this half-jokingly. キモかわいい is a recently established slang word coined similarly to this. See: [A different way to join i-adjectives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26019/5010)

To me ダサ面白い is a made-up word (I haven't seen this before), but it should mean something like "funny all the more for their un-coolness". I don't think ダサ is an intensifier prefix (like 超/バカ/クソ/ド).

Comment: `I don't think ダサ is an intensifier prefix (like 超/バカ/クソ/ド)` -> Totally agreed!

Comment: Thank you! Reading the text again, your translation seems to fit the general meaning.

Answer (score 2):

「ダッサ」 is a Yankee-style colloquialism for「ダサい」. It also can be used as an interjection (same as 「くそ」、「キメェ」、「ダセぇ」, 「スケベ」、 e.t.c.).

It may be strange to see that it's combined with a such positive word like 「面白い」, but in the fact that's a common way to emphasize on both of them in the same style of speech. You could also say 「くそ面白い」, 「くそ真面目」, e.t.c.

You will find more examples like that if you read manga a lot, or if you will go drink booze in all-male Japanese company.

Comment: Thank you! So basically, when it's not used with its literal meaning ("uncool"), it just emphasizes in a colloquial way the adjective it precedes, right?

Comment: Here it's both used and it literal meaning and emphasizes the next adjective in a colloquial way. I'd translate it as "it's uncool but [rudder word starting with "f"] interesting" in English.

Comment: I don't think it's common to use ダサ as an intensifier like クソ and バカ.

Answer (score 1):

ダッサ --> ださい

Means "uncool", "out of style" See [here](http://eitopi.com/dasai-eigo) for more info.

---

On a related note, you can often find words changed to this form for emphasis:

臭い｛くさい｝ -> クッサ！

うざい ->　ウッザ！

冷たい｛つめたい｝　-> 冷たっ!　　<-- similar abrupt stop for emphasis

Comment: Thank you very much for the link and the explanation provided! :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know the word, but
ダサ面白い is a trendy (new-ish) word, and was used to describe PM Abe as Mario.

----- as ----  が、意外に、このダサ面白さ、悪くはないかも…。

> 安倍首相のマリオ姿を世界はどう報じたのか 海外メディア､ネットの反応は ...
>   g-relations.jp/business-diary/1134/
>
> 2016/08/24 - が、意外に、このダサ面白さ、悪くはないかも…。しばらく経つと、じわじわとそう感じ始めた。果たして、このパフォーマンスは世界が注目するイベントにおいて吉と出たのか、凶と出たのか。海外メディア、インターネットの反応を探ってみた。