# When is it good to use "ダサい"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, offensive-words

When is it good to use "ダサい" (out of fashion, boring)? Is it an everyday word?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39057/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it an everyday word?

I think it certainly is used enough for it to be a popular parlace slang term most speakers will be familiar with.

> When is it good to use "ダサい" (out of fashion, boring)?

It helps me think of it as an approximate translation of *lame* and how speakers use that word in English. There might be a slight caveat in this though, in that ダサい seems to be directed more at what is considered by the speaker lame *fashion* and not exactly *attitude* per se, [as suggested by this answer in Chiebukuro asking about the difference between ダサい and カッコ悪い](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1199033616). So this would include "out of fashion".

For the general meaning of "boring" it is a harder fit in my opinion. I'd probably be using つまらない instead.